# Не работают внутренние запросы Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Итак, у меня имеется собственный mysql сервер, на котором по счастливой случайности располагаются нужные мне данные.

Суть проблемы:
У меня имеется большой запрос, который работает только если мы убираем условие связанное с message.id

```
convs.id as id,
#тип чата
convs.type as type,
#картинка
convs.cover as cover,
#название
convs.name AS name,
#уведомления
member.notfs AS notfs,
#текст сообщения
message.text AS text,
#сообщение от меня или нет
CASE
WHEN message.aid = acc.id
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as my,
#время
message.time as time

FROM
cute_conversation convs,
cute_conversation_member member,
cute_account acc,
cute_account sender,
cute_conversation_message message

WHERE
acc.id = 21 AND
member.aid = acc.id AND
member.status = 'in' AND
convs.id = member.cid AND
message.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM cute_conversation_message WHERE cid = convs.id LIMIT 1) AND
sender.id = message.aid
```

Однако, вложенный запрос, по отдельности, отлично выдаёт нужный max(id)

`SELECT max(id) FROM cute_conversation_message WHERE cid = convs.id LIMIT 1`

UPD: Ошибки нет, запрос с точки зрения синтаксиса верен и никаких ошибок SQL не выводится. Оттого и незамысловатый вопрос: почему?

Comment: Какую ошибку возвращает?

Comment: Ах, да, сейчас отредактирую. Ошибки нет, запрос с точки зрения синтаксиса верен и никаких ошибок SQL не выводится. Оттого и незамысловатый вопрос: почему?

Comment: Не достаточно чтобы там что-то было. У Вас условие фильтра `AND`. Это значит что для этого айди, которые возвращается вложенным запросом, должны быть подходящие статус и `acc.id`

Comment: Иначе говоря, у вас `max(id)` может быть `5` но для этих строчек `member.status ='out'` и из-за этого ничего не выведется

Comment: Проблема в том, что я проверял с этим вложенным запросом и без него, и конкретно после добавления этого запроса, ответ от базы пуст, но без него ```message.id``` рандомный

Comment: С ним он пуст а без него нет потому что с ним он добавляет условие которое не пересекается с остальными. Уберите его и посмотрите максимальный message.id того что получилось. Будет ли это значение соотв-ть возвращаемому подзапросом?

Comment: *запрос с точки зрения синтаксиса верен* Вообще-то нет. И именно в подзапросе. В его тексте имеется два поля, не оборудованные алиасом таблицы. Да, проблема не в этом, но тем не менее...

Comment: Допустим, но меня интересует любая кривая версия, главное чтобы дало результат, сейчас работаю не на качество, а на срок.